# took home with Emma after school

Tags: idiomatic-language

Emma's mom: *This is Emma's mom. I'm calling because your daughter's here. **She took home with Emma after school.***

Is 'took home with' correct here? Is it a natural thing to say? Thanks.

Comment: No, it does not sound correct or natural.  But you didn't tell us what you *want* to say, so it's hard to know how to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not something you would say in American English.

In this context, you would typically say **came**, for example:

> She **came** home with Emma after school.

However, if Emma's mom was still at work (at a different location), she might use **went**:

> She **went** home with Emma after school.

You can also say:

> Emma **took her home** after school.

In this case, **took** is a [transitive verb](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-3/verbs-types-tenses-and-moods/lesson-11/transitive-vs-intransitive-verbs). So it has to take action on an object. You can't say "She took home." You have to say "Emma took her home."

Comment: You would not say it in British or Canadian English either.